# How to do multi-task learning in torch7?

Tags: lua, torch

[Simple multi-task network can be done here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/OLjblK6iVl0) But I want something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnWgj.png).
Now I construct the model as below:

```
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.Linear(3,5))
prl1 = nn.ConcatTable()
prl1:add(nn.Linear(5,1))
prl2 = nn.ConcatTable()
prl2:add(nn.Linear(5,1))
prl2:add(nn.Linear(5,1))
prl1:add(prl2)
model:add(prl1)
```

And my output is:

```
input = torch.rand(5,3)
output = model:forward(input)
output
{
  1 : DoubleTensor - size: 5x1
  2 : 
    {
      1 : DoubleTensor - size: 5x1
      2 : DoubleTensor - size: 5x1
    }
}
```

How should I construct my criterion?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to figure it out through two steps:

1.Use nn.Concat instead of nn.ConcatTable in the above network, this make the output to be a simple NxM tensor, e.g. a 5x3 tensor will get in the above network while using nn.Concat instead of nn.ConcatTable.

2.After getting a NxM tensor, I use the combination of nn.ConcatTable, nn.Concat and nn.Select to make the output to be simple table that contain each result Tensor.

Here is a simple example of step 2:

```
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.Linear(3,5))

prl = nn.ConcatTable()

spl1 = nn.Concat(2)

seq1 = nn.Sequential()
seq1:add(nn.Select(2, 1))
seq1:add(nn.Reshape(1))

seq2 = nn.Sequential()
seq2:add(nn.Select(2, 2))
seq2:add(nn.Reshape(1))

seq3 = nn.Sequential()
seq3:add(nn.Select(2, 3))
seq3:add(nn.Reshape(1))

spl1:add(seq1)
spl1:add(seq2)
spl1:add(seq3)
prl:add(spl1)

spl2 = nn.Concat(2)

seq4 = nn.Sequential()
seq4:add(nn.Select(2, 4))
seq4:add(nn.Reshape(1))

seq5 = nn.Sequential()
seq5:add(nn.Select(2, 5))
seq5:add(nn.Reshape(1))

spl2:add(seq4)
spl2:add(seq5)
prl:add(spl2)

model:add(prl)

input = torch.rand(5,3)
output = model:forward(input)
```

The output will look like:

```
th> output
{
  1 : DoubleTensor - size: 5x3
  2 : DoubleTensor - size: 5x2
}
```